# Estimate just the constant coefficient in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, finance

How do I calculate the constant coefficient in logistic regression manually, i.e without having to use a calculator?

My model is

$g(Y) = X \beta + \alpha$

is it possible to calculate just the constant parameter $\alpha$ without performing the full regression fit?

Comment: Could you define alpha coefficient - there are many quantities that could be called "alpha"

Comment: I am using the Maximum likelihood estimate method. The expression is in the form a+xb1+xb2+xb3+xb4. I want to know how i can find the parameter 'a'.

Answer (score 4):

If all your predictors $(X_1, \dots, X_4)$ are zero centered then the constant term is what accounts for the class imbalance.

For example, if your sample has 100 `1s` and 400 `0s` then the overall background proportion of `1s` is 20%, and alpha will be such that $g(0.2) = \alpha$.  If you are using logit link function then $logit(0.2) = \alpha = -1.386$.

The constant is zero when the classes are balanced, negative when `1s` are "rare" and positive when `0s` are "rare".

As for not using a calculator, unless you have log tables to hand, you will need a calculator to take the logit (log-odds).

**Non-centered predictors**

If the predictors are not centered in the sample, then their offset acts like another constant term.  You would have to know the $\beta$ parameters to know how much constant each predictor is providing.  In this case however, the $\alpha$ parameter doesn't have a useful interpretation.  It is simply the log odds when all predictors are zero (which is a non-interesting point if they are not centered, and in some cases is an impossible point, since some predictors may not even naturally go through zero).